# What's current Django for "from django.views.generic import list_detail"?

Tags: python, django

Am I correct in understanding that "from django.views.generic import list_detail" has been deprecated and/or removed from Django?

If so, what is the appropriate successor?

Thanks,

--

@Gareth, thanks.

I have a followup question to ask: how do you use a ListView to replace a list_detail.object_detail?

The present code, which has been changed only in the import, is:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
#from django.views.generic import list_detail
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

from announcements.models import Announcement
from announcements.views import *


announcement_detail_info = {
    "queryset": Announcement.objects.all(),
}

urlpatterns = patterns("",
    url(r"^(?P<object_id>\d+)/$", list_detail.object_detail,
        announcement_detail_info, name="announcement_detail"),
    url(r"^(?P<object_id>\d+)/hide/$", announcement_hide,
        name="announcement_hide"),
    url(r"^$", announcement_list, name="announcement_home"),
)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview does not seem to suggest a single inline replacement for:

```
    url(r"^(?P<object_id>\d+)/$", list_detail.object_detail,
        announcement_detail_info, name="announcement_detail"),
```

If anything, it suggests an additional model be added, and that model be built on.

Is there a quick, inline replacement for the list_detail.object_detail call, or does it take more uprooting?

Thanks,

Comment: Breadcrumb remark: I made this post as part of a concerted effort to get a Pinax 0.7.3 social project to work with a more recent version of Pinax (for reasons beyond me, the social project in Pinax 1.0.0 is a bare stub, complete with lorem ipsum in the final page). It took me a lot of digging to get to Pinax 0.7.3 (there are innumerable places advertising a free Pinax 0.7.3 download, but I tried dozens and they all pointed to a pinaxproject.com (now) 404. Having found Pinax 0.7.3 and wanting to save other programmers the headache, I have made it available at http://JonathansCorner.com/pinax

Comment: Just published an article about migrating from function-based generic views to class-based analogs in Django [read the article](http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2013/12/come-migrare-dalle-viste-generiche-basate-su-funzioni-alle-analoghe-basate-su-classi-in-django/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`django.views.generic.list_detail` was [deprecated in Django 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/generic-views/#generic-views):

> From Django 1.3, function-based generic views have been deprecated in favor of a class-based approach.

Use [`django.views.generic.list.ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) instead.

Comment: Thank you; could you look at my edited page above and tell me how I might approach this aspect of porting?

Answer (score 8):

After importing `django.views.generic.list.ListView`

You just need to change `list_detail.object_detail` to `ListView.as_view()`