# how to replace list_detail by ListView in my django code

Tags: python, django, listview, python-2.7

I have a piece of code which uses django.views.generic.list_detail and works fine in older versions of python and django. I know that list_detail no longer exists in current versions and has replaced by [django.views.generic.list.ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) . But I haven't figured out how to replace my code so that in works like before. I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624509/whats-current-django-for-from-django-views-generic-import-list-detail) but I still got no clue.

This is my code (I got it from [here](http://www.djangobook.com)):

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic import list_detail
from mysite.books.models import Publisher

publisher_info = {
                    'queryset': Publisher.objects.all(),
                    'template_name': 'publisher_list_page.html',
                    'template_object_name': 'publisher',          >> **
                    'extra_context': {'book_list': Book.objects.all} 
                    }

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                    (r'^publishers/$', list_detail.object_list, publisher_info)
                    )
```

## publisher_list_page.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
                    <h2>Publishers</h2>
                    <ul>
                       {% for publisher in publisher_list %}       
                          <li>{{ publisher.name }}</li>
                       {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

I don't want to get my `views.py` involved in new code.

Can anyone help me with that please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide additional arguments to as_view method. For example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   (r'^publishers/$', ListView.as_view(
                       queryset=Publisher.objects.all(), 
                       template_name='publisher_list_page.html'
                   )))
```

But in your case you should to subclass generic views and provide your own get_context_data method, because `extra_context` keyword is no longer supported by the class based generic views

Comment: I was working on this line for hours and your code suddenly worked. Not sure what I've missed. Thank You.