# Deprecated Package Syntax in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using an older textbook, and the guide is telling me to include the following imports in my `urls.py`

```
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list, object_detail
from django.views.generic.create_update import create_update
```

From what I understand, these have been deprecated in an earlier version of Django - but I can't figure out what the modern implementation would be.

Would that also affect my url patterns?

```
url(r'^$', object_list, dict(display_info, allow_empty=True)),
url(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', object_detail, display_info),
url(r'^add/$', create_object, create_info),
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate question [  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624509/whats-current-django-for-from-django-views-generic-import-list-detail ]

Comment: @NakulNarayanan it looks like my question is slightly different as I am dealing with  object_list and object_detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
```

instead of

`from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list, object_detail` 
`from django.views.generic.create_update import create_update`

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import include
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from .views import SampleView



    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
        path('sample-app/', include('sample_app.urls')),
        path('sample-view/', SampleView.as_view(), name="sample_view"),

    ]
```

please refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/) for more info for class based views 

please refer  [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/) for more info for URL routing

Comment: Thanks for that information. How about my URL Patterns? I don't see how to fix those.